# How to delete array element from JSON array of objects by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, ecmascript-6

This is probably quite easy, but giving me trouble. Given this JSON structure:

```
 "playlists" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "owner_id" : "2",
        "song_ids" : [
          "8",
          "32"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id" : "2",
        "owner_id" : "3",
        "song_ids" : [
          "6",
          "8",
          "11"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id" : "3",
        "owner_id" : "7",
        "song_ids" : [
          "7",
          "12",
          "13",
          "16",
          "2"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

How would you delete an object from the array by key/value? In this case by ID? playlist.splice(1,1)?  playlist.delete(id)?  Not sure how to do this elegantly. Let's say I wish to delete the element with ID = 3, how to get this result:

```
 "playlists" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "owner_id" : "2",
        "song_ids" : [
          "8",
          "32"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id" : "2",
        "owner_id" : "3",
        "song_ids" : [
          "6",
          "8",
          "11"
        ]
      }
]
```

Comment: Could use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which will return a copy of the array with the filtered out elements removed.

Comment: Or, you could use [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of an element with given ID, then [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove that element. I've written you an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71940546/979052) below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), you can filter out elements that don't match a certain condition. For example:

```js
const result = playlists.filter(playlist => playlist.id !== '2');
```

Here's a working demo:

```js
/* Example Data */
const playlists = [
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "owner_id" : "2",
    "song_ids" : [ "8", "32"]
  },
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "owner_id" : "3",
    "song_ids" : ["6", "8","11" ]
  }
];

/* Takes a list of playlists, and an ID to remove */
const removePlaylistById = (plists, id) =>
  plists.filter(playlist => playlist.id !== id);

/* Removes playlist ID 2 from list, prints result */
const result = removePlaylistById(playlists, '2');
console.log(result);
```

---

Another option, would be to use [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of an element with given ID, then use [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove that element. This will modify the array, without the need for a copy.

For example:

```js
const indexToRemove = playlists.findIndex((pl) => pl.id === '2');
playlists.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
```